# Expression blend beginner

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

I am a newbie in expression blend. I googled it many times for getting some tutorials for expression blend for a beginner. But I don't get any simple tutorial that a beginner can understand the basics of EB. I really need to study it for making better UI for the windows phone applications am developing.

Can anyone suggest me some tutorial links of expression blend for a beginner. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

expression blend is used to customize controls, create vector images and also for animations. You can find the article in you tube for everything. e.g [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbNQOzFl1u8) clip can tell you about the control template editing at beginner level.

Comment: Thank you. I never searched in youtube for coding yet.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this one:

http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/school/

Nice lessons from MS.